# How to calculate inverse of modulo (remainder) operator?

Tags: functions, relations, inverse, inverse-function

I am running a C++ program with two arrays`vec` and `nums` which are related as:

```
vec[(i + k) % (nums.size())] = nums[i]
```

Edit:
Writing it in math:
$y = (x + k)\mod n$
Where $k$ is a constant smaller than the size of both arrays (which are equal) and $i$ is a variable iterating over both arrays. $n$ is a constant (size of array).
x is the independent variable and y is  the dependent variable.
I asked, what would x be equal to in terms of $y$, $k$ and $n$ ?

I wanted to ask, given the above relation between `vec` and `nums` what would be the inverse of this relation? That is:

if `vec[i] = nums[x];`

what would the value of $x$ be in terms of $i, k$ and `nums.size()`?

This is a math question regarding inverting a relation with a modulo in it, and not a programming question. Hence, I posted it here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: (i - k) % (nums.size())

Comment: It's a math question, but it's presented in code; I have no idea what vec[(i+k etc means. Can you rewrite it in math?

Comment: @GerryMyerson edited the question, please do check

Comment: "both arrays" – which things are the arrays? and where does $i$ show up?

Comment: vec and nums are the arrays, i ranges from 0 to n-1.

If you're not familiar with C++, i think that can be ignored. i have edited the question and written the relevant code using x and y. y =f(x)  is given, it involves a mod function. I want to find the inverse of f(x).

Comment: Still confusing. How do "vec" and "num" relate to $x$ and $y$? Anyway, if $y\equiv x+k\pmod n$, why don't we just get $x\equiv y-k\pmod n$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

We have $i \pmod{n}\equiv  (x+k) \pmod{n}$ where we just have to solve for $x$.

By doing a subtraction, we have $x \pmod{n} \equiv i-k \pmod{n}$.

```
vec[i] = nums[i-k];
```

If you perform a circular shift by $k$ steps to the right of nums to get vec, to reverse the process, we perform $k$ steps circular shift to the left of vec to get back nums.